# IIS 6.0 UTF8 support for local email robért@domain.com

Tags: iis, smtp, utf-8

IIS 6.0 UTF8 support for local email rob**é**rt@domain.com
2 hours, 38 minutes ago|LINK

Is there anyway for IIS 6.0 to handle the local part of the email with UTF-8 Characters - robért@domain.com

I have the correct code.

```
mMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(recepient, recepient, Encoding.UTF8))


'Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
    Dim mSmtpClient As New SmtpClient()
    mSmtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International
    ' Send the mail message
    mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage)
```

I have tested with a really great developer tool called PaperCut which was adjusted to accept UTF-8 local part of email. - https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut (Be sure to use the development branch).

Comment: IIS 6.0 is far past end of life and it should have been decommissioned years ago. It is unlikely you will ever have a solution for this, other than to upgrade to something which is currently under support.

Comment: Believe it or not IIS6.0 is still used with Windows Server 2016 and is the SMTP server of IIS http://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2016/01/add-smtp-windows-server-2016/   I have posted here and IIS.net.   I do not think this is possible, gmail, yahoo and outlook online free email services do not allow for UTF-8 characters --- é

Comment: OK, that's rather frightening. If it were me, I would go look for some other SMTP server.

Comment: LOL, I ask Scott Hanselman about it.  Maybe I will get an answer.  This is the Hunt for the Red October.